# how to join user to a channel created in twilio with android

Tags: android, twilio, chat, twilio-api

I have 2 apps on Android, in my app Patient is where I create my client using a token to create a channel in Twilio, my created channel is the following **1Doc_3Pac** that is saved in a string, I can join this channel from Patient app without problem using the channel method .join. But when I try to join this channel from my Nursing app using the same method, create a client and then join a channel I can not find it. It seems to me that the method I use is not adequate here I leave my code.

Here I create my client with the token.

```
 public void build(String token, final TaskCompletionListener<ChatClient, String> listener) {
        ChatClient.Properties props = new ChatClient.Properties.Builder()
                .createProperties();

        buildListener = listener;
        ChatClient.create(context.getApplicationContext(),
                token,
                props,
                this);
    }
```

Here I create my channel with the Client

```
public void createCustomizedChannel(String name, final TaskCompletionListener<Channel, String> listener) {
            mChannelsObject.channelBuilder()
                    .withFriendlyName(name)
                    .withType(Channel.ChannelType.PUBLIC)
                    .build(new CallbackListener<Channel>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(final Channel newChannel) {
                            if (newChannel != null) {
                                listener.onSuccess(newChannel);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(ErrorInfo errorInfo) {

                        }
                    });
        }
```

Here joined to my channel customized created

```
public void joinChannel(final Channel channel, final TaskCompletionListener<Channel, String> listener) {
        channel.join(new StatusListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                listener.onSuccess(channel);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(ErrorInfo errorInfo) {
                super.onError(errorInfo);
            }
        });
    }
```

And in my Nurse App I don't  find my channel **1Doc_3Pac**

```
 private void loadChannels() {
        mChatClient.getChannels().getChannel("1Doc_3Pac ", new CallbackListener<Channel>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Channel channel) {
                if (channel != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Joining Channel: " + DEFAULT_CHANNEL_NAME);
                    joinChannel(channel);
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Creating Channel: " + DEFAULT_CHANNEL_NAME);

                    mChatClient.getChannels().createChannel(DEFAULT_CHANNEL_NAME,
                            Channel.ChannelType.PUBLIC, new CallbackListener<Channel>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Channel channel) {
                                    if (channel != null) {
                                        Log.d(TAG, "Joining Channel: " + DEFAULT_CHANNEL_NAME);
                                        joinChannel(channel);
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onError(ErrorInfo errorInfo) {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "Error creating channel: " + errorInfo.getMessage());
                                }
                            });
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(ErrorInfo errorInfo) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error retrieving channel: " + errorInfo.getMessage());
            }

        });
```

falls on the onError method with this message

> Channel not found

Comment: you can find channel using channel sid

Comment: channel sid ? How do I do that ? You give me some code or some simpler way to do it @ShwetaChauhan

Comment: okay, adding some code

Comment: hey, check https://github.com/ShwetaChauhan18/TwilioProgrammableChat
not whole completed but basic you got. Still it's under developemnt

Comment: This proyect is in kotlin. I need java

Comment: Are you able to list out the public channels in the nurse app with [getPublicChannelsList](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/android/chat/releases/4.0.3/docs/classcom_1_1twilio_1_1chat_1_1Channels.html#ab93e29cd8742a0e33b52142037387ac2) and can you see the channel you are looking for? Are you using the same Chat service SID for both applications?

Comment: service? to create a channel I do it with a client, then this channel name that I get from getFriendlyName () I store it in a string, and I pass a string through a json to the Nurse App, where with my method loadChannels () I search, but I get an error. If you would be so kind as to provide me with an example code or something to understand you better. @philnash